# MongoDB suddenly crash down and API not able to connect MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, pm2

I am running NodeJS API application with MongoDB on AWS EC2 instance (eu-west-2 region) with PM2, It was working fine from 2 to 3 months.it was working properly until I last worked on 03rd July 02:30PM (UTC), But then at 04th July 05:56AM (UTC), when I see pm2 logs it was not able to connect MongoDB.Error was "MongoDB connection error { MongoError: failed to connect to server [] on first connect".So I started MongoDB again and it started working properly.

I opened the MongoDB logs, And I find, at 03rd July 08:30PM(UTC) there was something like this: "I [conn] Successfully authorised "" as "" ". And then very next log was for 04th July 05:56AM (UTC): "I [main] **** SERVER RESTARTED ****" (which is when i restarted MongoDB).There was no logs between there lines. Don't know what is problem, Is there any problem with my code, with my server or DB or with AWS EC2 instance (I have enough space on it).
Thank You.

Comment: Is your machine configured to start mongod after system reboot? If not there are plenty of solutions on that already like this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/862255

Comment: @Anton Thanks for comment, in my case, When I hit pm2 restart <id>, it automatically connects to MongoDB.